# Google Apps for Business on a separate infrastructure?

Tags: g-suite, gmail, google

Does anyone know if Google Apps for Business edition hosts the apps (gmail, calendar, etc.) on a physically separate infrastructure than the Standard (free) infrastructure?  We've been growing increasingly annoyed with the lost/severely delayed email messages, downtime, etc. of Google Apps (standard) over time, and we are wondering if moving to the paid version would bring any benefits.  Specifically, if the Business edition is not in some way on a different physical infrastructure, and we are in essence paying for a few small perks but still run on the usual standard/free setup, then we would probably have the same (or just as many) issues with the Business version.

I've emailed Google's sales team responsible for GApps, but haven't heard anything back in 4 days, which already doesn't speak well for the service.  So, anyone have any insight into this?

Thanks in advance for any and all help :)

Comment: This is a little odd. I have two free Google Apps domains that make heavy use of web email and IMAP, calendar, xmpp. I haven't seen downtime in a long while and I find the XMPP service to be considerably more reliable than MSN Messenger.

Answer (score 1):

Google is pretty much silent on how their physical infrastructure works, but the Business edition of Google Apps does have a SLA agreement

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/terms/sla.html

You can also see their service history on the Apps Status Dashboard

http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin.  Yeah, I've seen the SLA stuff and the dashboard.  The SLA would at least imply to me that there is some sort of separation between the platforms, but I'm still not sure. Plus, even on days when loads of people are complaining about Gmail issues (twitter, etc.) and we are experiencing issues as well, the dashboard says things are just fine, so over time I've become skeptical of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, google apps for business is run from the same infrastructure as the rest of google apps. There are some that run on a separate infrastructure (early adopters, I believe), but these are being transitioned back into the main infrastructure.

You can tell if a given google apps account is being run from the core infrastructure by trying to load one of the apps email accounts alongside a regular gmail account on the same browser session. If you can open both at once, they're on separate infrastructure. If you can only open one at a time, they're in the same infrastructure.

Comment: Actually there's another case where you can be on separate infrastructure - Some folks have google accounts that conflict with their corporate email accounts e.g. at home one evening you could register a google account as fred.smith@supercompany.com and later when supercompany.com moves to google apps, there's a new account fred.smith@supercompany.com. To move to the main google apps pool, you have to resolve those conflicts.